# Звук при стрельбе начинает трещать и гудеть

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть звук стрельбы, он протяжённый около 2 секунд, а стрельба быстрая.

Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы звук начинался всегда заново, а когда прекращаем стрелять, он продолжался до завершения.
Как мне это сделать?
Когда делаю так:

```
if (!Sound.isPlaying) {
    Sound.Play();
    Shot.Hit();
}
```

Он стреляет раз в 2 секунды.
А когда делаю так:

```
Sound.Play();
Shot.Hit();
```

Он жутко начинает дребезжать и гудит со страшной силой.
Как правильно сделать?

Всё это обрабатывается в `Update`.
Используется `AudioSource`.

Comment: У вас условие `!Sound.isPlaying` точно один раз отрабатывает? Такое ощущение, что у вас просто кучу раз один и тот же звук стартует.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, вы как вопрос читаете? Причем тут `Sound.isPlaying` ? С ним все в порядке... речь без использования его, ибо он делает задержку Мне и нужно один и тот же звук запускать раз в 0.5 сек, так, чтобы когда стреляешь он заного воспроизводился, а когда перестаешь он продолжался и заканчивался уже через 2 секунды.

Comment: Что значит `А когда делаю так`? Вы вызываете `Sound.Play();Shot.Hit();` в `Update` без этой проверки `if (!Sound.isPlaying)`?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, Зачем она мне нужна? она дает задержку в 2 секунды..... Мне надо каждый раз запускать  звук, а если перестаем прекращать через 2 сек.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Все оказалось проще некуда

```
if (Time.time > (ShotTime + Speed)) {
    Sound.Stop();
    Sound.Play();
    ShotTime = Time.time;
}
```

Comment: А теперь попробуйте выстрелить, свернуть игру и развернуть.

Comment: Для таких вещей нужно использовать `Time.deltaTime`.